# Combine $(this) and $("li:eq(ui.item.index())")

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

With jQuery, how can i combine `$(this)` and `$("li:eq(ui.item.index())")` to something like `$(this).$("li:eq(ui.item.index())").id` ?

I'm trying to get the id attribute of a list element within a sortable list created with jQuery UI kit

```
$(".sections-list").sortable({ /* Update position of sortable elements */
    start: function(event, ui) {
        var start   = ui.item.index();
        var section = $("li:eq(start)").id;

        alert(section);
    }
});
```

Comment: `.id` isn't a property of jQuery objects.

Comment: ofc.. Got it to work with `attr("id")` .. thanks

Answer (score 7):

Assuming what you're trying to do is find a specific indexed `li` item below `this`, you can do it like this:

```
$(this).find("li").eq(ui.item.index()).attr("id")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also pass `this` as a second argument to `$()`, indicating the context for your search:

```
$('li:eq('+start+')',this).attr('id')
```

Answer (score 2):

If the elements you are trying to find are descendants of the `$(this)` object, then you can use jQuery's `.find()` function.

```
$(this).find("li:eq("+ui.item.index()+")").id
```

If the elements you are looking for are siblings of `$(this)` then you can use the `.siblings()` function to find them -

```
$(this).siblings("li:eq("+ui.item.index()+")").id
```

Reference -

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find(selector);
```

The find selector takes your initial jquery and searches again within it.

Read more on it here: http://api.jquery.com/find/